# find all the controls avaliable in a application(win application) by passing process ID in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to find all the controls avaliable in a application.
Is it possible to interact application to application. I need to set value from my application to another application(windows) running in my system in a particular control.

Comment: which type of data want to paste?

Comment: i need text data to paste.

Answer (score 1):

This code will get all the control values associated with process running in the system.In this code there are 2 file 1.ApiWindow is a class file and other the main() class. Main() will use the ApiWindow class and get the control values as the Spy++ tool works. We can handle the controls and can set value to specific control using   SendMessage(child.hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "Ur Value")
This hwnd will get the handle id and WM_SETTEXT will pass a message to update the given text. Declare  WM_SETTEXT  as global variable
like  Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC .

Note: While running the program Make Visual Studia "run as Administrator"

Code :

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class ApiWindow
Public MainWindowTitle As String = ""
Public ClassName As String = ""
Public hWnd As Int32
End Class

''' <summary> 
''' Enumerate top-level and child windows 
''' </summary> 
''' <example> 
''' Dim enumerator As New WindowsEnumerator()
''' For Each top As ApiWindow in enumerator.GetTopLevelWindows()
'''    Console.WriteLine(top.MainWindowTitle)
'''    For Each child As ApiWindow child in enumerator.GetChildWindows(top.hWnd) 
'''        Console.WriteLine(" " + child.MainWindowTitle)
'''    Next child
''' Next top
''' </example> 
Public Class WindowsEnumerator

  Private Delegate Function EnumCallBackDelegate(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  ' Top-level windows.
  Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumCallBackDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  ' Child windows.
  Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hWndParent As Integer, ByVal lpEnumFunc As EnumCallBackDelegate, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

  ' Get the window class.
  Private Declare Function GetClassName _
   Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpClassName As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer

  ' Test if the window is visible--only get visible ones.
  Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

  ' Test if the window's parent--only get the one's without parents.
  Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer

  ' Get window text length signature.
  Private Declare Function SendMessage _
   Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

  ' Get window text signature.
  Private Declare Function SendMessage _
   Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As StringBuilder) As Int32

  Private _listChildren As New List(Of ApiWindow)
  Private _listTopLevel As New List(Of ApiWindow)

  Private _topLevelClass As String = ""
  Private _childClass As String = ""

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Get all top-level window information
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <returns>List of window information objects</returns>
  Public Overloads Function GetTopLevelWindows() As List(Of ApiWindow)

    EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowProc, &H0)

    Return _listTopLevel

  End Function

  Public Overloads Function GetTopLevelWindows(ByVal className As String) As List(Of ApiWindow)

    _topLevelClass = className

    Return Me.GetTopLevelWindows()

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Get all child windows for the specific windows handle (hwnd).
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <returns>List of child windows for parent window</returns>
  Public Overloads Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Int32) As List(Of ApiWindow)

    ' Clear the window list.
    _listChildren = New List(Of ApiWindow)

    ' Start the enumeration process.
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, AddressOf EnumChildWindowProc, &H0)

    ' Return the children list when the process is completed.
    Return _listChildren

  End Function

  Public Overloads Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal childClass As String) As List(Of ApiWindow)

    ' Set the search
    _childClass = childClass

    Return Me.GetChildWindows(hwnd)

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Callback function that does the work of enumerating top-level windows.
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="hwnd">Discovered Window handle</param>
  ''' <returns>1=keep going, 0=stop</returns>
  Private Function EnumWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

    ' Eliminate windows that are not top-level.
    If GetParent(hwnd) = 0 AndAlso CBool(IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) Then

      ' Get the window title / class name.
      Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)

      ' Match the class name if searching for a specific window class.
      If _topLevelClass.Length = 0 OrElse window.ClassName.ToLower() = _topLevelClass.ToLower() Then
        _listTopLevel.Add(window)
      End If

    End If

    ' To continue enumeration, return True (1), and to stop enumeration 
    ' return False (0).
    ' When 1 is returned, enumeration continues until there are no 
    ' more windows left.

    Return 1

  End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Callback function that does the work of enumerating child windows.
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="hwnd">Discovered Window handle</param>
  ''' <returns>1=keep going, 0=stop</returns>
  Private Function EnumChildWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lParam As Int32) As Int32

    Dim window As ApiWindow = GetWindowIdentification(hwnd)

    ' Attempt to match the child class, if one was specified, otherwise
    ' enumerate all the child windows.
    If _childClass.Length = 0 OrElse window.ClassName.ToLower() = _childClass.ToLower() Then
      _listChildren.Add(window)
    End If

    Return 1
   End Function

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Build the ApiWindow object to hold information about the Window object.
  ''' </summary>
  Private Function GetWindowIdentification(ByVal hwnd As Integer) As ApiWindow

    Const WM_GETTEXT As Int32 = &HD
    Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Int32 = &HE

    Dim window As New ApiWindow()

    Dim title As New StringBuilder()

    ' Get the size of the string required to hold the window title.
    Dim size As Int32 = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)

    ' If the return is 0, there is no title.
    If size > 0 Then
      title = New StringBuilder(size + 1)

      SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, title.Capacity, title)
    End If

    ' Get the class name for the window.
    Dim classBuilder As New StringBuilder(64)
    GetClassName(hwnd, classBuilder, 64)

    ' Set the properties for the ApiWindow object.
    window.ClassName = classBuilder.ToString()
    window.MainWindowTitle = title.ToString()
    window.hWnd = hwnd

    Return window

  End Function

End Class
```

''' There the Main function class starts

```
 Imports System.Text

Module Module1
 Private Declare Function SendMessage _
   Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As String) As Int32

    Const WM_GETTEXT As Int32 = &HD
    Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Int32 = &HE

    Const WM_CREATE As Int32 = &H1
    Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
    Sub Main()
        Static count As Integer = 0
        Dim enumerator As New WindowsEnumerator()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        For Each top As ApiWindow In enumerator.GetTopLevelWindows
            count = 0
            Console.WriteLine(top.MainWindowTitle)

            For Each child As ApiWindow In enumerator.GetChildWindows(top.hWnd)
                Console.WriteLine(child.MainWindowTitle)

               'here you can find the value of control you  want and can can set the required

               ' count = count + 1
               ' If (child.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Initial value in text box")) Then
                  '  Console.WriteLine(count.ToString)
                    'Console.ReadKey()

                'End If

                'now find the count of ur control in the sample page and set the values
               ' If (count = 104 And top.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Form1")) Then
                    'SendMessage(child.hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "required Textbox value")

              '  End If



            Next child

        Next top
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

  End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

If you persist the data from one app to a means you feel is acceptable; database, text file, xml. Then one app updates the persisted data store and the other app checks the data store for the info.

Comment: the spy++ tool will find the controls in the application. but i need to set value after find the control without interaction database. and only one application i can handle other or 3rd party  application i dnt have access to UI code. please refer the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx#S8